# Change of Image control from static to dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach

I am having 6 Image controls which get the images from the folder through URL in the database. The point is that i am doing it statically. I want to change it over to dynamic by using for loop or for each loop but i am not getting an idea how to do it. In future if the number image controls increases so it is hard to specify each an every one statically.

I am using asp Image tag.

so far the code works fine as static but i want it make it dynamic using some loop.

code which i have tried so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            var strURL = context.retrieveImage()
                    .Select(s => s.image_url)
                    .ToList();

            Image1.ImageUrl = strURL[0];
            Image2.ImageUrl = strURL[1];
            Image3.ImageUrl = strURL[2];
            Image4.ImageUrl = strURL[3];
            Image5.ImageUrl = strURL[4];
            Image6.ImageUrl = strURL[5];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImageList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
    {
        var strURL = context.retrieveImage()
                .Select(s => s.image_url)
                .ToList();
        rptImageList.DataSource = strURL;
        rptImageList.DataBind();            
    }
}
```